# Python - fastest way to save data in big xlsx file that already exists

Tags: python, pandas, openpyxl, xlsx, xlsxwriter

I know this problem has been asked few times already but most of those questions are from 2013 - 2017. And I thought that maybe something changed in 2021 and there is an answer for that.

What I need to do is to save (overwrite) df into first sheet of xlsx file that already exists and has other sheets in it.

I do have code that works but it takes alot of time (below are times for 16 MB xlsx file):

start of code:

**2021-08-12 16:22:10.153751**

converting xlsx file to csv and reading csv as df:

**2021-08-12 16:23:15.977594**

opening another xlsx file where i want to overwrite data with df:

**2021-08-12 16:27:48.855185**

saving xlsx file with sheet1 data overwriten with my df:

**2021-08-12 16:30:45.739699**

As you can see it takes almost 7 minutes to have it done and that is quite long time.

Below is my code:

```
from xlsx2csv import Xlsx2csv
import datetime
import pandas as pd
from openpyxl import load_workbook

pathOpen = r'D:\EXCEL_FILES\Bazowe_S21.xlsx'
pathSave = r'D:\EXCEL_FILES\Bazowe_KOMB.xlsx'

print(datetime.datetime.now())

Xlsx2csv(r'D:\EXCEL_FILES\Bazowe_S21.xlsx', outputencoding='utf-8', delimiter=';').convert(r'D:\EXCEL_FILES\Bazowe_S21.csv')

dataFrame = pd.read_csv(r'D:\EXCEL_FILES\Bazowe_S21.csv', sep=';', low_memory=False, encoding='utf-8')

print(datetime.datetime.now())

# save data in 1st sheet of xlsx file that already exists
book = load_workbook(pathSave)
sheetN = book.sheetnames[0]
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(pathSave, engine='openpyxl')
writer.book = book
writer.sheets = dict((ws.title, ws) for ws in book.worksheets)
dataFrame.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=sheetN, index=False)

print(datetime.datetime.now())

writer.save()
writer.close()

print(datetime.datetime.now())
```

I would appreciate any tips in speeding this process up.

Comment: pd.read_csv is very slow, either try another csv loading library or if you just load the csv and id doesn't change often you can load it once as csv and then store it as pickle, which is multiple magnitudes faster then excel and csv loads.

Comment: Bear in mind that Microsoft Excel files are actually compressed archives of (mainly) xml files. If your Excel file is 16MB on disk then it's going to be a lot bigger than that once all the embedded files are decompressed and loaded into memory. Therefore, just guessing, but you may be constrained by the available RAM on your machine

Comment: Reading csv file was not the problem i asked for solution. Its the end of the program where I save df to xlsx file that takes ages and I thought that there is a way to speed it up.

Comment: Things will be a little faster if you don't load the workbook into Pandas.